# Using .Find() & .Include() on the same query

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following method automatically generated from the scaffold template with repository:-

```
public Group Find(int id)
{
    return context.Groups.Find(id);
}
```

But since the Groups object has two navigation properties which I need , so I wanted to include the `.Include`, so I replace the `.find` with `.where` :-

```
public Group Find(int id)
{
    return context.Groups.Where(c=>c.GroupID==id)
                         .Include(a => a.UserGroups)
                         .Include(a2 => a2.SecurityRoles)
                         .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

But my question is how can I apply the `.Include` with the `.find()` instead of using `.Where()`?

Comment: you can simplify even more by passing your filter to the single call and dropping the where clause eg `.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.GroupID==id)`

Comment: so what are the differences between .Where and .Find??

Comment: Take a look here at the differences between where and find, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx, basically find only searches by key and has a subtle optimisation if you have previously queried for the entity. This is optimisation is actually the underlying reason you cant use an include

Comment: you can do this in EF core 5.0
`return context.Groups.Include(a => a.UserGroups).Include(a2 => a2.SecurityRoles).FirstOrDefault(c => c.GroupID == id);`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was just thinking about what find actually does. @lazyberezovsky is right **include and find cant be used in conjunction with each other**. I think this is quite deliberate and here's why:

> The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value to attempt to find
>   an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the
>   context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity
>   there. Null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or
>   in the database.
>
> Find is different from using a query in two significant ways:
>
> - A round-trip to the database will only be made if the entity with the given key is not found in the context.
> - Find will return entities that are in the Added state. That is, Find will return entities that have been added to the context but have
>     not yet been saved to the database.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx)

Because find is an optimised method it can avoid needing a trip to the server. This is great if you have the entity already tracked, as EF can return it faster.

However if its not just this entity which we are after (eg we want to include some extra data) there is no way of knowing if this data has already been loaded from the server. While EF could probably make this optimisation in conjunction with a join it would be prone to errors as it is making assumptions about the database state.

I imagine that include and find not being able to be used together is a very deliberate decision to ensure data integrity and unnecessary complexity. It is far cleaner and simpler
 when you are wanting to do a join to always go to the database to perform that join.

Comment: but the idea of finding an object that is in the Added state , but not yet added to the Database is scary and can cause inconsistent results ,, what do you think ?

Comment: @johnG yeah I agree it is a bit wierd, Im not 100% on the rules around this but it could be that this only works on entities with manually defined keys. if it works with entities with auto generated keys there's a definite possibility that when you actually add them to the DB they wont actually get the key you were thinking it would. In either case my personal preference has always been to use .SingleOrDefault or .FirstOrDefault to find entities in the database

Answer (score 7):

You can't. [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method defined on [`DbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) type and it returns entity. You can't call `Include` on entity, so the only possible option is calling `Find` *after* `Include`. You need [`DbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) type for that, but `Include("UserGroups")` will return [`DbQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696530%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), and `Include(g => g.UserGroups)` will also return [`DbQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696530%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string path) 
    where T: class
{
    RuntimeFailureMethods.Requires(source != null, null, "source != null");
    DbQuery<T> query = source as DbQuery<T>;
    if (query != null)    
        return query.Include(path); // your case
    // ...
}
```

[`DbQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696530%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is not a child of [`DbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) thus method `Find` is not available. Also keep in mind, that `Find` first looks for entity in local objects. How would it include some referenced entities, if they don't loaded yet?

Comment: on that note, im not a huge fan of find anyway, .FirstOrDefault() or .SingleOrDefault() fulfil a similar purpose and work on any IEnumerable

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I believe First() and similar will always hit the database though.

Comment: If you're calling Include it's going to hit the database for the ancillary data anyway, might as well have it do it all in one query if possible.  Unless it's a poorly optimized or a massive table that is going to cost a lot of time or server resources, you're probably better off just using FirstOrDefault.  My favorite thing about Find is the fact that my repositories don't need to have knowledge of the name of the key field, though...

Comment: Find is handy when you are in a generic scenario where you don't know the type you are finding at design time and cannot use `FirstOrDefault()` or any similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
public static class DbContextExtention
{
    public static TEntity FirstOfDefaultIdEquals<TEntity, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> source, TKey otherKeyValue)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "ID");
        var equal = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(otherKeyValue));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal, parameter);
        return source.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
    }
    public static TEntity FirstOfDefaultIdEquals<TEntity>(
        this ObservableCollection<TEntity> source, TEntity enity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var value = (int)enity.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(enity, null);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "ID");
        var equal = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(value));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal, parameter);
        var queryableList = new List<TEntity>(source).AsQueryable();
        return queryableList.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
    }
}
```

GetById:

```
public virtual TEntity GetByIdInclude(TId id, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var entry = Include(includes).FirstOfDefaultIdEquals(id);
        return entry;
    }
```

Method include EntityFramework Core ([look here(EF6 and EF Core))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812386/use-include-method-in-repository):

```
protected IQueryable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object> query = null;

        if (includes.Length > 0)
        {
            query = DbSet.Include(includes[0]);
        }
        for (int queryIndex = 1; queryIndex < includes.Length; ++queryIndex)
        {
            query = query.Include(includes[queryIndex]);
        }

        return query == null ? DbSet : (IQueryable<TEntity>)query;
    }
```