# MVC 5 Updating multiple fields of one row in database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm practicing MVC 5 and in my application I have a controller method that should update address info for a given user profile.

I do this by accessing the database with a context object, and my first thought was to copy the database row to an object, make the changes and then put it back using the `AddOrUpdate()` method. However, I only see an `Add()` method.

So instead I did the following:

```
public ActionResult EditBillingDetails(EditBillingDetailsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).FirstName = model.FirstName;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).LastName = model.LastName;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).Email = model.Email;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).Address = model.Address;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).City = model.City;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).ZIP = model.ZIP;
        db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id).Country = model.Country;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeBillingSuccess });
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Which works just fine, but it feels wrong to go look up the same entry 7 times just to update each field one by one. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's best practice to wrap `IDisposable` objects in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block, and your `ApplicationDbContext` should be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `db.SaveChanges()` will take care of updating an entity with new values if you retrieved it from the database.  EF "tracks" entities that you query from the database (in this instance, the call to `.Single()`) and knows to persist changes back to the databse if you alter any properties of that entity.  You only have to `Add` to the database if you are creating a completely new entity.

```
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id);
user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
user.LastName = model.LastName;
user.Email = model.Email;
user.Address = model.Address;
user.City = model.City;
user.ZIP = model.ZIP;
user.Country = model.Country;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Great, that's almost like pointers. I didn't know EF did that. This might be a little off topic: Can EF handle migrations to multiple context types? I've got one for application data and one for users and roles. I've only been able to add migrations to one. Have to go into the other database and make changes "by hand".

Comment: @Scopperloit  Migrations are dependent on if you are using Database First or Code First.  Your users and roles are probably using Asp.Net Identity, which is Code First.  If you have an existing database for your other parts, then you set that up as Database First.  On Database First, yes, you have to make changes to SQL, then update your model.  Code First is opposite - you update your model, which generates SQL scripts to update your Database.  Either is fine and both work identically once the model and DB are in sync.

Comment: why use `.Single()` instead of `.Find()`?

Comment: @Djeroen - see here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17581985/130387).  `.Find()` can be quicker than `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()` etc but is only beneficial in certain situations and is the equivalent of the above in most others.  For example,  `.Find()` will not return a complex query (imagine if the User object has additional navigation properties, those would need to be queried later).  For me, its a preference to forgo the slight performance gain in order to ensure I know what I am getting back from the db and not have to think about if I am going to use an attached property or not.

Comment: @Djeroen - just one more thought.  `.Find()` checks to see if an entity is already in the object graph as an 'added' entity, it returns it from cache.  Given the Unit of Work pattern, it would be rare that I query the same entity twice during a single request (I consider it a code smell to ask for the same object twice and not reuse the one I already have), therefore, I most likely will never see the performance increase from the returning a cached object part of `.Find()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Entity-Framekwork and you haven't changed any default configurations (caching), your code, although very specific, only the first `Single()` will make the database call to retrieve the object.  So functionally it would be the same as:

```
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id);
user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
user.LastName = model.LastName;
user.Email = model.Email;
user.Address = model.Address;
user.City = model.City;
user.ZIP = model.ZIP;
user.Country = model.Country;

db.SaveChanges();
```

There may be a additional (so minor) code execution depending on if the compiler would change your code in IL to the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the user from the context?

```
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    DbContext context = new YourDbContext();
    return context.Users.Find(id);
}

public void SaveUser(User user)
{
    DbContext context = new YourDbContext();
    context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    return;
}
```

In your Controller, you would update the User's properties and save it:

```
DbContext context = new YourDbContext();
User user = GetUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());
user.Value1 = model.Value1;
user.Value2 = model.Value2;
SaveUser(user);
return RedirectToAction(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult EditBillingDetails(EditBillingDetailsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        Users usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
        if(usr != null)
        {
            usr.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            usr.LastName = model.LastName;
            usr.Email = model.Email;
            usr.Address = model.Address;
            usr.City = model.City;
            usr.ZIP = model.ZIP;
            usr.Country = model.Country;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeBillingSuccess });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = "Error" });
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

> The logic is to get details from database only once and update all the fields for it.
>
> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy paste solution.

Comment: Especially if `usr == null`, it will throw an exception, never getting to the `if` code.

Comment: It will not throw an exception, rather it will not do anything and just return the view. This should be fine as in this case we just want to edit existing data from the database not create new one.

Comment: [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) - The Single<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method throws an exception if the input sequence is empty. To instead return null when the input sequence is empty, use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Additionally, most business cases do not involve returning a success view if there in face were no updates and no success had.  An error should be returned to the end-user stating as such.

Comment: I concur your thoughts Erik / Tommy - I have made changes to the post to reflect your views. Thanks :)