# Generic Repository GetByID method with "Including" ....

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to add a method to my generic repository that will allow me to query an entity by it's PrimaryKey (ID) and select what navigation properties to return. The kicker is, that in order to be truly generic I do not know the data type or field name of the Primary Key (Not supporting compound keys ... yet).

So here's what I started with ... the below snippet gets me the TEntity based on  key regardless of the TYPE of the key ...

```
 public virtual TEntity GetByID(Object entityID)
 {
     TEntity ret = DbSet.Find(entityID);
     return ret;
 }
```

The next step was to get records back, but including whatever navigation fields I chose to include ... This worked out great for that ... for multiple records.

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includedProperties)
    {
        var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var prop in includedProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(prop);
        }

        return query;
    }

   //
   // example usage gets ALL books including Author and Publisher information
   var repo = uow.GetRepository<Book>();
   repo.GetAllIncluding(e=>e.Author, e=>e.Publisher);
```

So now I need to mix the two ... here's the rub. In order to dynamically add the "including" expressions I need to convert the DbSet to an IQueryable ... however in order to leverage the type-agnostic key lookup I need to use the "Find()" method on the DbSet ...

So in theory I need to convert the DbSet to an IQueryable, add the Include expressions then convert the IQueryable BACK to a DbSet so that I can access the type-agnostic "Find()" method ... this does not work ...

Anyone got any ideas on how this can be done ... ??

---

Here's some pseudo-code for what I am trying to get to work ...

```
    public virtual TEntity GetByID(Object entityID, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includedProperties)
    {
        var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var prop in includedProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(prop);
        }


        TEntity ret = ((DbSet)query).Find(entityID);
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: The Generic Repository is often considered an anti-pattern: http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/ - have you considered alternative architectures?

Comment: I address these concerns (some at least) by using a component layer which I refer to as a sort of "service layer" which provides the specialization and translation from data-centricity to something more "domain" for the application layer to consume. The application (should) never interact directly with the Repository. I could, in theory, swap out my SQL Server database for a MySQL or ORACLE database and the "service layer" would insulate the application from the change. It makes the Repository a back end tool. The "service" layer is the one on the "Frontline" ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .Find() & .Include() on the same query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576283/using-find-include-on-the-same-query)

Comment: While the topic is the same, it does not address whether we can lookup on the PK even if we do not know it's field name and data type. I cannot necessarily use ... where (e=>e.ID = entityID) ... because the key might be named "KEY" for example and one may be a VARCHAR type and another may be a BIGINT type. Are we saying that because we can't use "Find()" with "includes" that what I am hoping to do cannot be done?

Comment: The answer is the same to me. `Find` uses an optimization step which is incompatible with `Include`. So what you are trying to do isn't meant to be possible.

Comment: So this is IMPOSSIBLE? There is no way to find a generic entity by it key (whatever that may be) and pre-load it's navigation properties?