# How to Serialize specific model in entity framework using asp mvc wep api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

so i have a database that hold a table called userinfo that has name, phone, photo etc.
another tables called customers and representative, they are in one to one relation with my userinfo table.

i'm trying to create a web api controller to get & post data for the customer class, i want to send back the users data in the customer table and the related record in the userinfo table , but i don't want to send the related data in the customers city table as an example.

the ironic thing is my action is sending back every thing that is related to the customer even other customers who are related to the same city, and it goes for every table in my database. (almost sending back the full database)

i want to know how to send only one customer model without any other related data in other tables.
and how to send back a a list of cities without any customer related data.

the api action method looks like this ;

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id )
        {
            var c = db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (c== null) { return NotFound(); }
            return Ok(c);
        }
```

and i've added the following code to my WepApiConfing.cs

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

i've attached an image  of the return json , i'm not sure it did not return my customer user info  thought :/

it's high lighted in blue

[image: here]

Comment: That is because you are sending back the entire entity with all its navigation members. create a DTO (Data transfer object) that contains only the properties you want going over the wire and copy them over from the entity.

Comment: It is generally recommended to use view models to send data to your views. You should avoid sending data models to the views, because often it is not suitable for views either by format, details, privacy, or security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find doesn't really do what you think it does, it fetches an item from the DB **only if its not in the graph already** (which by the looks of your results it is). If it is in the graph, it returns the cached version.

You are seeing some of the navigation properties (eg `.Job`) populated as you have done other queries which have fetched these previously.

Find also doesn't allow you to use an `Include` which will help you load related entities (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581985/1070291 for more details as to why).

What you will want to do is to use an include query something like:

```
db.Customers
    .Include(x=>x.UsersInfo)
    .Include(/*other things you want to load*/)
    .SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
```

This will fetch the item and any associated parts you tell it to from the DB.

Comment: you were right about not using the find method , the FirstOrDefault method did send only the customer model , but when i added the Include , i went back to ground zero , it sent all the data again not only the class i Included

Comment: by the way i needed to add
using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: @magdi that sounds a bit weird that you are getting other graph entities populated only on .Include. 

The recommendation with EF is that you only use your context for a unit of work (a request in webapi is probably your unit of work). If you create your context only for this scope it wont have lots of other things in there in the first place (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx) Dependency injection can also be used to manage the context lifecycle (I personally use ninject .InRequestScope)