# Add Include to repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

I have a working repository.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

As I read in coding repositories, that you don't add any class until you really need it. Now, I need to add **Include**. I found this one in this community [Use Include() method in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812386/use-include-method-in-repository):

```
public static class IncludeExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
                                                   params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
                                                   where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = null;
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            query = dbSet.Include(include);
        }

        return query ?? dbSet;
    }
}
```

Then, I changed it to fit in my code (As I think) to be:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Include(IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
                                    params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> query = null;
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query = dbSet.Include(include);
    }

    return query ?? dbSet;
}
```

With direct access to context, I am able to write:

```
Provinces = _cmsDbContext.Provinces.Include(c => c.District).Include(c => c.District.Country).ToList();
```

But, with repository, I can't write:

```
Provinces = Currentunitofwork.ProvinceRepository.Include(c => c.District).Include(c => c.District.Country).ToList();
```

I got error:

```
cannot convert lambda expression to type IDbSet<Province> because it is not a delegate type
```

What is the problem here, please.

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity;` in your code file?

Comment: Is this method being added to the Repository class?

Comment: @Ashwin Nair. I am using them already, otherwise, even with direct using of context will not work.

Comment: @Adam Carr. Yes, this method is in the same class of repository **Repository<TEntity>**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your code is passing in the lambda expression to the IDbSet parameter and can not convert it to that type.

I have not been able to test but it compiles, if the method is a member of the Repository class then try this.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();

    IEnumerable<TEntity> query = null;
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query = dbSet.Include(include);
    }

    return query ?? dbSet;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't compile. error: **cannot conver method group 'Set' to non-delegate type**

Comment: Yes that was a typing mistake! I have updated with the correction.

Comment: Please, Help me in including more than one entity. With that method, I am able to include just one entity. Now, I need to include three entity through the repository. Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that is 100% possible, the purpose of using repositories is to isolate the functionality out to specific functions.  By offering this you are basically reverting back to the DbContext, which would defeat the purpose of the repository in the first place.

Comment: You would also be better of asking another question as well as you can get better input on the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't post anymore, StackOverflow thinks that all programmers are guru!. Anyhow, I managed to find a solution, I change the code to: `public IEnumerable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExpressions) => includeExpressions.Aggregate(Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable(), (q, e) => q.Include(e));`

Comment: `public IQueryable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExpressions)` has a params so you could possibly pass in multiple expressions as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Again thanks to @Adam Carr.

This is the method code now:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();

    IQueryable<TEntity> query = null;
    foreach (var includeExpression in includeExpressions)
    {
        query = dbSet.Include(includeExpression);
    }

    return query ?? dbSet;
}
```

What I change is use **Set** as a method not a property. So, instead of:

```
IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>;
```

I used:

```
IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
```

Also, I used **IQueryable** instead of **IEnumerable**.

Comment: So AdamCarrs answer should have been the accepted one?