# Use ThenInclude() method in Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was looking for some hours how to implement the extension method called `ThenInclude()` in my repository. I have implemented the `Include()` method with the help of @Brian Habrock in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980745/11476247.

But now my project requires one more level of complexity using `ThenInclude()` method.

I have this on my `_BaseRepository`:

```
public IQueryable<E> Include(params Expression<Func<E, object>>[] includes)
{
    IIncludableQueryable<E, object> query = null;

    if (includes.Length > 0)
    {
        query = dbSet.Include(includes[0]);

    }
    
    for (int queryIndex = 1; queryIndex < includes.Length; ++queryIndex)
    {
        query = query.Include(includes[queryIndex]);
    }

     return query == null ? dbSet : (IQueryable<E>)query;
}
```

My IBaseRepository:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<E> where E : class
{
    IQueryable<E> Include(params Expression<Func<E, object>>[] includes);
        
}
```

Currently I'm searching on how to do the following:

```
_myEntityARepository
    .Include(x=> x.EntityB)
    .ThenInclude(x=> x.EntityC)
```

How can I resolve/create the `ThenInclude()` method?

Thanks.

Comment: Taking a look at EntityFramework's source code on GitHub could shed some light on it.

Comment: Will _this_ be when you realize writing your own repository is a waste of time, or will you wait for the next thing you have to figure out how to re-implement?  Just let the repository's consumer add any `Include` or other final query shaping by simply handing out `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you have just won the award for best comment of the day for "*Will this be when you realize writing your own repository is a waste of time*"

Comment: Just to reiterate the point above, in perhaps clearer terms: Entity Framework is *already* an implementation of the repository and unit-of-work patterns. Writing another repository around it is a double abstraction which ends up making life difficult as you've already seen